# How to acces an int from the main class in another class in java?

Tags: java

I have an int a; in the main class and i'd like to use it in the Action Listner class. I've checked for answers but didnt really understand what i had to do since I'm still just a begginer in any kind of programing so if its possible i'd really appreciate a simple solution.

here is my code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


 public class Start {
public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame okno = new JFrame("Nonogram");
    okno.setVisible(true);
    okno.setSize(700, 700);
    okno.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    okno.add(panel);

    JButton [][] gumbi = new JButton[15][15];

    JPanel polje = new JPanel(new GridLayout(15, 15));
    panel.add(polje, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    int a = 1;
    int b = 1;

    for(int i = 0; 0 < 15; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 15; j++){
            if(i < 5 && j < 5){
                gumbi[i][j] = new JButton();
                gumbi[i][j].setBackground(Color.RED);
                //gumbi[i][j].addActionListener(new Listener(gumbi));
                polje.add(gumbi[i][j]);
            }else if(i < 5 || j < 5){
                gumbi[i][j] = new JButton();
                gumbi[i][j].setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

                //gumbi[i][j].addActionListener(new Listener(gumbi));
                polje.add(gumbi[i][j]);
                gumbi[i][j].setEnabled(false);

            }else{
                if(Math.random() <= 0.6){
                    gumbi[i][j] = new JButton();
                    gumbi[i][j].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    gumbi[i][j].addActionListener(new Listener(gumbi));
                    gumbi[i][j].setText("3");
                    polje.add(gumbi[i][j]);
                }else {
                    gumbi[i][j] = new JButton();
                    gumbi[i][j].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    gumbi[i][j].addActionListener(new Listener(gumbi));
                    gumbi[i][j].setText("4");
                    polje.add(gumbi[i][j]);
                }
            }

            if(gumbi[i][j].getText() == "3"){
                a += 1;

            }
            if(i == 14 && j == 14){
                gumbi[i][j].setText("" + a);
            }
        }
    }


}
}
```

and this is what i have in Action Listener

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;


public class Listener implements ActionListener {
JButton[][] gumbi;

public Listener(JButton[][] gumbi)  {
    this.gumbi = gumbi;

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    JButton gumb = (JButton) e.getSource();

    if( gumb.getBackground() == Color.WHITE){
        gumb.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    } else if (gumb.getBackground() == Color.BLACK){
        gumb.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }
}


}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: It's declared in a `main` method which makes it a local variable. It won't be accessible from anywhere.

Comment: in your current implementation int a  is defined in main method and anything declared in a method will be local to the method, you really have to get the basics right , for now u can define the int a public static int a outside the main method ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define that `int a` as static with public access and remove it's definition from within your main method as below:

```
public class Start {
    public static int a = 1;//static since you want to use in static method
    public static void main(String[] args){
```

And then in your listener call, you could use .variable like below:

```
int number = Start.a;
```

Answer (score 1):

in your current implementation int a  is defined in main method and anything declared in a method will be local to the method, you really have to get the basics right , for now u can define the int a public static int a outside the main method , and then access the variable with the class name reference as shown below

```
public class Start {

    public static int a ;
    public static void main() {
         //your logic
    }
}

public class Listener implements ActionListener {
    int temp = Start.a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with another answer that you can make a static in the main class, there might be a neater solution, even though that it is not exactly what was asked.

Instead of attempting to get the value of a from the main, it makes more sense to send along the value of a in the constructor of `Listener`.

```
public class Listener implements ActionListener {
  JButton[][] gumbi;
  final int a;

  public Listener(JButton[][] gumbi, int a)  {
    this.gumbi = gumbi;
    this.a = a;
  }

...
```

In the main method simply change the method that adds the listener as follows:

```
gumbi[i][j].addActionListener(new Listener(gumbi, a));
```